# How do I add classes to multiDexKeepFile in flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I enabled multiDex in my Flutter app because the number of references exceeded 64k. I read online that I should enable multiDex to fix this. I did this. But now I keep getting this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

I also read elsewhere that I need to add my classes to the `multiDexKeepFile`to fix this error, but I can't figure out how to do this for Flutter. How and what classes do I add? Can someone help me, please? I've been stuck on this problem for days. I even tried reducing the number of plugins I use, with no luck.

The plugins I use are:

```
flutter:
sdk: flutter
rxdart: ^0.18.1
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
cloud_firestore: "^0.7.3"
google_sign_in: "^3.0.4"
firebase_auth: "^0.5.15"
```

[![This is my build.gradle file in android/app/build.gradle
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q55U.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q55U.png)

The error is thrown when I press on the button. I'm assuming the error has to do with `await loadingModal(context: context, asyncFunc: fetchCourses);` because no error is thrown when that line is commented out
[image: My Button Code]

The `loadingModal` method is defined in another file called `loading_modal.dart`
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you share some code? For Example: Gradle file.

Comment: I added pictures of my code and where the error is being thrown

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was being caused by firebase_auth. Upgrading firebase to `firebase_auth: ^0.6.2+1` and following the steps on: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex
solved the issue for me, and there was no need to make a multiDexKeepFile file.